# WooCommerce additional fee checkbox on archive page

Tags: checkbox, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I make a shop page with WooCommerce, where the single product page disabled. On the archive page there's a quantity input field and before that I like to add an additional fee checkbox. This code doesn't work, and I don't know where to modify to add that fee to the cart and checkout. Could you please help me out? Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
// FRONTEND
function additional_fee() {
    if ( has_term( array( 'test' ), 'product_cat' ) ) {
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="additional-fee" value="No">Additional Fee';
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'additional_fee' );

// STORE DATA
function store_additional_fee( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['additional-fee'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['additional-fee'] = $_POST['additional-fee'];
    }
        return $cart_item_data;
    }
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'store_additional_fee', 10, 3 );

// ADD TO CHECKOUT
function add_checkout_additional_fee( $cart_object ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( isset( $cart_item['additional-fee'] ) ) {
        $ndmtransferfee = true;
        $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
        break;
        }
    }
    $fee = 5000;
    if ( $ndmtransferfee ) {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( __('Additional Fee', 'textdomain'), $fee * $quantity );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_checkout_additional_fee', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Ajax add to cart on shop and archive pages, doesn't handle custom input fields like an additional checkbox, that's why it doesn't work. You should better try to explain in your question editing it what you are trying to do with that checkboxes (what are they for?). Then in the search [try this search for cart + checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+cart+checkbox) or [try this search for checkout + checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+checkout+checkbox)… Then think different and try other things. If you have an issue, ask a new question.

Comment: Thans for your reply and advice LoicTheAztec, seems it's a better way to add a checkbox to the cart section! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's managed to work based on LoicTheAztec reply. Thanks!